# How to have an ActionResult not redirect the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have an HttpPost in my controller that requires an object from my model. It then returns an HttpStatusCodeResult depending on success of the action. On my view, I want to run some basic javascript based on the status code result instead of redirecting to a new page. I would simply do this with AJAX but I need to send the object with a form. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your form and send it via ajax. Your model binding will work fine. Send a response which your client side js code can read and execute your CUSTOM functions then.

Example, You might have a create view with a form like this

```
@model CreateCustomerVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

and the script to handle the form posting

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var frm=$(this).closest("form");
    $.post(frm.attr("action"),frm.serialize(),function(res){
        //do something with res here'
        // if(res.Success)
        // {
        //  alert(res.Message)
        // }
    });

  });
});
```

So your `HttpPost` action method should read the posted form, Do whatever it needs to do  and send a response back, like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCustomerVM model)
{
  // to do : Read from model and save
  // someService.Save(model)
  return Json(new { Success = true, Message="Saved successfully"});  
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like what I need. I wasn't sure how to send the object info into an httppost I guess.